# TypeScript: How to wrap a function, changing its return type?

Tags: typescript

I need to write a function like this:

```
const wrapper = (fn) => () => {
  const value = fn.apply (this, arguments)
  const somethingElseEntirely: WellDefinedType = doMagic (value)
  return somethingElseEntirely
}
```

...that wraps any given function. It is known that given function returns a well defined type, say, `string`. It is also known that given function can accept any combination of arguments, and the wrapped function should take the same arguments, *however*, it should return a different type of value.

E.g., a function like:

```
function foo (arg1: string, arg2?: number): string
```

...should become:

```
(arg1: string, arg2?: number): WellDefinedType
```

Is this possible to achieve in TypeScript without resorting to `any`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TypeScript 3.0 recently introduced new features](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) allowing you do exactly this.

```
declare function wrapWithNumberReturn<A extends any[]>(fn: (...args: A) => any): (...args: A) => number

declare const concat: (a: string, b?: string) => string

// returns (a: string, b?: string) => number
const wrapped = wrapWithNumberReturn(concat)
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20function%20wrapWithNumberReturn%3CA%20extends%20any%5B%5D%3E(fn%3A%20(...args%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20(...args%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20number%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20concat%3A%20(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3F%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20string%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20returns%20(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3F%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20number%0D%0Aconst%20wrapped%20%3D%20wrapWithNumberReturn(concat)%20)

Comment: Is migration to TypeScript 3.0 from 2.8 an easy and reasonable thing to do, as of August 2018?

Comment: Not a lot of changes between those two versions other than new features, so I'd say it probably wouldn't be too difficult