# Typescript - Change function return type

Tags: typescript

I want to override a function changing its return type. I've found this approach, [TypeScript: How to wrap a function, changing its return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996138/typescript-how-to-wrap-a-function-changing-its-return-type). However, I'd like a more generic one.

```
type Test = (
    a: string,
    b: string,
    c: number,
) => string | Promise<string>;

type Test2 = (
    a: string,
    b: string,
    c: number,
) => number | Promise<number>;
```

What I expect is something like:

```
// CopyFunction(Function, Return)
type Test2 = CopyFunction(Test, number | Promise<number>);
```

Comment: More generic how ? the type `CopyFunction` would be `type CopyFunction<TFn, TR> = TFn extends (...a: infer A) => any ? (...a:A) => TR: never
type Test22 = CopyFunction<Test, number | Promise<number>>;`

Comment: When I say generic, I was talking about the return type. The solution that you provided is exactly what I need. Thanksssssssss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a type that uses conditional types and tuples in rest parameter to do what you want:

```
type CopyFunction<TFn, TR> = TFn extends (...a: infer A) => any ? (...a:A) => TR: never    
type Test22 = CopyFunction<Test, number | Promise<number>>;
```

Comment: This is great, works like a charm.  Using it for a parent type that passes in the TR argument to make it dynamic